# Unable to capture exception on error page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm trying to print out the an exception stack trace on a jsp page. However, the implicit exception object doesn't seem to be populated.

```
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
 xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<jsp:directive.page isErrorPage="true" />
<spring:message var="title" code="error_uncaughtexception_title"/>

    <h2>${fn:escapeXml(title)}</h2>

    <p>
        <spring:message code="error_uncaughtexception_problemdescription"/>
    </p>
    <c:if test="${not empty exception}">
        <p>
            <h4>
                <spring:message code="exception_details"/>
            </h4>
            <spring:message var="message" code="exception_message"/>

                <c:out value="${exception.localizedMessage}"/>

            <spring:message var="stacktrace" code="exception_stacktrace"/>

                <c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="trace">
                    <c:out value="${trace}"/>
                    <br/>
                </c:forEach>

        </p>
</c:if>
```

The page is properly configured in web.xml:

```
 <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/uncaughtException</location>
    </error-page>
```

Any guesses as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exception` implicit object is available as a page variable (i.e. for scriptlets) but is not available as an EL reference.

You can access the exception state using the `${pageContext.errorData}` expression (see [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro4.html)), which is an object of type `javax.servlet.jsp.ErrorData` (see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/ErrorData.html)).

See [J2EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro4.html) for examples.

Comment: thanks interestingly enough, i pulled that code from a Spring Roo project. It appears they make the same error.

Comment: I just tried adapting a Roo-generated exception page and found this question with the same problem.  It turns out Roo uses [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html) to get "exception" mapped in those views.